# Web API controller fails with The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I have a controller with Get that returns `Ok(data)`. `data` is a list of objects which can be serialized manually without errors using Json(data). But when I return it from the controller it fails with the following error if I run from Curl:

```
    {"message":"An error has occurred.","exceptionMessage":"The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to
     serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.",
    "exceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","stackTrace":null,"innerException":
    {"message":"Anerror has occurred.","exceptionMessage":"Unable to translate Unicode character \\uD835 at index 935 
    to specified code page.","exceptionType":"System.Text.EncoderFallbackException","stackTrace":"   
    at System.Text.EncoderExceptionFallbackBuffer.Fallback(Char charUnknown, Int32 index)
    at System.Text.EncoderFallbackBuffer.InternalFallback(Char ch, Char*& chars)   
    at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetBytes(Char* chars, Int32 charCount, Byte* bytes, Int32 byteCount, EncoderNLS baseEncoder)\r\n   
    at System.Text.EncoderNLS.GetBytes(Char* chars, Int32 charCount, 
    Byte* bytes, Int32 byteCount, Boolean flush)\r\n   
    at System.Text.EncoderNLS.GetBytes
    (Char[] chars, Int32 charIndex, Int32 charCount, Byte[] bytes, Int32 byteIndex, Boolean flush)
at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush(Boolean flushStream, Boolean flushEncoder)\r\n   
at System.IO.StreamWriter.Write(String value)\r\n   
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextWriter.WriteNull()\r\n   
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.AutoCompleteClose(JsonContainerType type)\r\n   
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.WriteEndObject()\r\n   
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.WriteEnd(JsonContainerType type)\r\n   
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.WriteEnd()\r\n   
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.AutoCompleteAll()\r\n   
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextWriter.Close()\r\n   
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.Dispose(Boolean disposing)\r\n   
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.System.IDisposable.Dispose()\r\n   
at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding)\r\n   
at System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content)\r\n   
at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.<WriteBufferedResponseContentAsync>d__1b.MoveNext()"
```

I have exception handling for the controller but it doesn't go there. On the client side in Angular I see only  `(failed)net::ERR_FAILED`.

If I replace with `return Ok()` it works fine, I get 200.

This is my

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore };

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    }
```

Comment: There's not a lot we can do without knowing more about what `data` is. Though the exception does say `Unable to translate Unicode character \\uD835 at index 935 to specified code page`. That character is UTF-16 I believe.

Comment: What serializer did you use to manually serialize data ? Was it `DataContractJsonSerializer` ?

Comment: At a glance, it looks like a surrogate pair is cut off between two code points belonging to said pair, perhaps because of a (partial) buffer flush. Can you create a [mre] including relevant data? What also could be happening is that the source data is simply incorrectly encoded, and that the code that doesn't throw (`return Json(data)`?) uses a fallback of using an empty string for invalid code points.

Comment: added my `WebApiConfig`

Comment: @DavidG I can see that but where do I catch the error?

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is I was using Substring on a Unicode string and it was creating non existent character and serializer was crashing